# Avg equity on flop vs range

Tags: software, equity

I'd like to calculate the average of the equities on the flop in Texas Holdem for a particular starting hand vs. particular ranges. PokerStove can nicely do this except that it calculates the equities on the river and in example, I would like to see what if I call a 2bet from the blinds -say- with 65s and what would be my average equity on the flop versus the range of all pocker pairs etc. Is there any free or non-free software out there which can make these calculations?

Comment: I'm confused.  Given that you know only your hole cards and are willing to assign a range to your opponent, how is there any difference between "equity on the flop" and "equity on the river"? When you generally calculate flop equity, you are also including the possible turn and river cards that may come.

Comment: Are you, by the way, trying to find a way to play hands like `65s` as cheap as possible only to see the flop and justified by the investment? `65s` for example has around `20%+/-` to hit either a flush or a straight draw. There's no `equity` on flop. You play the hands based on initial investment.

Answer (score 2):

Pokerstove is able to calculate the equity on flop (just don't enter the turn and river cards before calculating the equity)

there are plenty of other tools around that do it, I personally use Pokerstrategy Equilab and this does exactly what you are looking for as well.